# generate automatic tables with intellij

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship. so I used the @JoinTable annotation to configure the table that was going to be generated by hibernate. But intellij says that there is no such table in the database, which is fine since I put it in persistence.xml so the tables are created automatically. In order to solve this problem, I had to use only the a note, dog @ManyToMany.
[intellij error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUE9i.png)

I would like to know how I can intellij allow me to use @joinColumn even without the table still exists since it will be created automatically

Comment: What is the issue/question?

Comment: I would like to know how I can intellij allow me to use @joinColumn even without the table still exists since it will be created automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ isn't forbidding you from doing this.  Because you have the Persistence/JPA facet active in your project, it is trying to reach out to your database to determine if your mappings are sane.

The reason IntelliJ is upset at all is either:

- Because you don't have a database connection configured in your project, or
- You *do* have a database connection but the tables are actually *wrong*.

Sans context I can't tell which one it is for certain, but I'd say this is safe to regard as a warning and not an error.